# what is the difference between child and parent component in angular 2,

Tags: angular

Specifically, what are parent components and child components , hate it that all tutorials , documentations brush over this, Am making an angular 2 app and have the basic understanding of what components are however when reading on how to pass data between components all references refer to "child/parent component interaction" which one cannot get well if as for my case i do not know the difference between the two.

Answer (score 10):

A parent component is a component that has a wider scope and a child component is a component that is apart of that scope but not all of it. One example is an html page that has a toolbar, a content area and a table inside the content area.

If we look at a pseudo html it looks like:

```
<html>
  <toolbar></toolbar>
  <content>
    <table></table>
  </content>
</html>
```

Looking at this we say `content` is a parent component that has a child of `table` and `toolbar` is a sibling to `content`.

Let's say that `content` has some data that it wants to pass down to render in `table` then in the parent component (content) you would write the necessary logic to get that data bind it to a variable then in the html template property bind that variable to `table` so it can be rendered.

Pseudo html again:

```
<html>
  <content>
    <table [tableData]="contentData"></table>
  </content>
</html>
```

Hope this is clear and helps

Comment: thanks, you gave a simple and direct explanation , however what do you mean by "toolbar is a sibling to content"

Comment: It's on the same level as content either are siblings

Comment: Follow up question would be - Are parent/child components "always determined" from the template (html) ? I am referring to this in context of apps based on frameworks like Angular, React, EmberJS, etc

Answer (score 1):

A parent component is like a container for child components. A child component is a more specific part inside a parent component. Example would be a parent component being a PERSON. ARMS and LEGS are child components of it.